# Why does this else condition not meet code coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, if-statement, code-coverage

I'm confused about why the following `if/else` condition doesn't meet code coverage. Specifically the `else` is getting flagged as not having coverage.

```
if (myBoolean) {
    myComponent.myElement = 'Hello world';
} else {
    myComponent.myElement = 'Hello everyone';
}
```

I can refactor this to set the value of `myComponent.myElement` prior to the `if` condition, and that seem to pass fine.

```
myComponent.myElement = 'Hello everyone';
if (myBoolean) {
    myComponent.myElement = 'Hello world';
}
```

Why wouldn't the `else` condition pass as well?

Comment: Do you have a test where myBoolean is false?

Comment: @NathanHughes I don't. But wouldn't the `else` cover that?

Comment: There seems to be some fundamental misunderstanding what "code coverage" means. It's a measure of how much of your code is executed during testing. If during testing you only ever exercise (run) this code where `myBoolean` is true, then the first code block will be covered (i.e. has been executed as part of a test) and the second code block will not (i.e. has never been executed as part of the test). The primary method of increasing code coverage is to write tests that exercise the uncovered code paths. **tl;dr** add a test that reaches that code when `myBoolean` is false.

Comment: What do you think “code coverage” means? You must execute each branch (typically via test cases) for to be considered “covered” by the tests. If you don’t run (cover) each branch, you don’t know if they both work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The coverage tool records which lines of code your tests cause to be executed.

If your flag is set by reading some input, then the flag is used to decide which branch to take, the test will follow either one path or the other. If your code under test checks for invalid inputs, code handling that won’t be executed by a test using valid inputs. You will need a test for each possible case so that all the paths get covered.

By the way, the coverage tool is useful not just for the statistics it generates but for confirming the test does what you think it does. If a test fails you can look at the coverage and see how far it got and which branches were executed.